# SharePoint Design Workflow: Workflow 2010: How to set Status Column based on value of calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, calculated-column

I have been pulling my hair out, new to workflows. Trying to set the value of a status column (choices:  Completed/Closed; Past Due Need Assistance; Approaching Due Date - Focus Needed; On Target) based on value in a calculated column.

My calculated column is named **Complete Date Empty** and is `=IF(ISBLANK([Complete Date]),"Yes","No")` set to single line of text.

Then I set a variable workflow called **Complete Date Empty** and set value to No.

If the workflow variable of no equals the calculated column then I want my status set to Completed/Closed. When the workflow runs it sets the current item always to Completed/Closed, even when the calculated column is Yes.

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your workflow is truly mysterious in construction.

There are a couple of potential issues here, but the first question is why you are taking the approach of creating a calculated column to check against a variable, and not just checking the completed date field directly?

Check your data type - when using such comparisons, always verify whether you might be checking a *Yes/No* value against a *string* value of "No"?

As best I recall, a 2010 workflow will pull a yes/No as True/False, so your If should return false rather than true (I would expect your problem to be that nothing is marked completed rather than the other way around).

Try getting rid of that first If statement, and start with:
If "Current Item:Complete date" is greater than 1/1/1901

Additionally, all your later if statements are incorrect. Since created date is always equal to itself (as is the modified date equal to itself), your first Else statement won't be run (you placed it on the wrong If as it should likely be one up on the if which sets status to completed).

Your last If checking variable time will always resolve true as you've placed it within the less than or equal to 0 check (anything less than 0 is certainly less than 14). I would actually expect all your results to be "Approaching Due Date".

Comment: Thank you for your response, I changed to a variable because I could not get the checking against the completed date to work but perhaps it is because of the entire workflow as written?  Can you suggest a better workflow to make this work?  I redid it to this but still having no luck.  Thank you for your help, it is greatly appreciated as I learn this new process!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out,  like I said I'm brand new to workflows in SharePoint and have no IT background but I finally got it to work:
[image]